# Were there communes in Imperial Germany?

Tags: germany, imperial-germany

I wonder about the territorial division of Imperial Germany.

The empire was divided among 26 states (in German *Bundesstaaten*).

Each of them had an internal division system which of course differers from state to state.

It appears that Prussia and the Grand-duchy of Baden had a 3-level administrative division,

while other states had either 2 levels or just 1-level division.

The lowest division was a Circle (in German *Kreis*) which consisted of

either 1 city, or a dozen of Rural villages, or in some cases, both.

My question is, were the Circles divided into communes (in German *Gemeinde*)

that consisted of only one or possibly two villages?

I find no trace of German communes before 1945, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

*Kreise* and *Gemeinden* (or *Ämter* - sg.: *Amt*, which was the smallest sub-unit in Baden) **developed independently from each other**. Additionally, they **developed in different ways depending on the state's constitution**. For example, with the reforms during/after Napoleon's reign in central Europe, **Prussia** and **Bavaria** enacted laws to create and develop *Gemeinden* in their territory: In Bavaria, [Gemeindeedikte <sup>WP, german</sup>](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemeindeedikt) were issued 1808 / 1818; in Prussia, the [Städteordnung <sup>WP, german</sup>](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preu%C3%9Fische_Reformen#St.C3.A4dtereform) created a unified legal base for *Gemeinden* throughout the state.

The commune's most important peculiarity was their **autonomy** regarding certain tasks and competences that rest on a state in behalf of its citizens. In other words, the *Gemeinde* as organizational unit gave their citizens the means to regulate certain issues independently from the state's government, especially some fiscal matters. So, the primary "opposite" or counterpart of the *Gemeinde* wasn't the *Kreis* or *Bezirk*, but the state. Belonging to a certain Kreis was primarily an administrative issue without grave political consequences. The main issue was the relationship of the *Gemeinden* regarding the state, the distribution of power and political authority and amount of fiscal autonomy between state and *Gemeinde*. In modern times, distribution of competences between *Gemeinden* and upper-level bodies like *Kreise* or *Bezirke* is a matter of dispute quite often (esp. since those questions affect the economic autonomy of the *Gemeinde*), but i doubt whether this was true already during the 19th century.

The *Kreise* were partly established in the same time (e.g. in Baden), partly later, e.g. in Prussia beginning in 1880, in Bavaria as *Bezirke* (later, Bavaria divided the *Bezirke* into *Kreise*). WP Commons has a [nice map illustrating the situation of the *Reich* in the year 1900](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Karte_Deutsches_Reich,_Verwaltungsgliederung_1900-01-01.png). German Wikipedia has a [complete list of the Kreise that were established in the different states of the German *Reich*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschichte_der_Kreisbildung_in_Deutschland).

So: yes, *Gemeinden* already existed in the German *Reich*, but not  necessarily as a part of *Kreise*. Since *Kreise* served as a means to "encapsulate" multiple smaller units, i wouldn't expect to find a *Kreis* encompassing only one *Gemeinde*. Instead, even nowadays, there's the concept of [*kreisfreie / kreisunmittelbare Stadt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_city#Germany) (literally "circle-independent city") - that's a city that doesn't belong to a *Kreis*, but fulfils the tasks of a *Kreis* itself.

Comment: So in other words, communes existed (at least in Prussia and Bavaria) but they weren't territorial ?!

Comment: I'm not sure about the meaning of "territorial". Communes did exist and belong to certain states. They may have been part of some some intermediate entity like a Kreis or a Bezirk, but that was solely an administrative fact. It was much more important that the communes were (and still are) solely responsible for certain tasks and duties. I've understood your question as if there were states and Kreise, and the Kreise were subdivided into communes. This situation is simply be the result of a long development, but it doesn't imply that the Kreise were first, and then the communes were created.

Comment: I do not understand, we probably have a major understanding problem there. For me a "commune" is a territory that encompasses only one village or town (or possibly a village and one or a couple of small hamlets), and is the smallest division within a country. Switzerland works like that, but France and modern Germany also does. The *Kreise* were definitely much larger than that, encompassing at least a dozen of villages and in many cases even more.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i mean, too, and that's also the meaning of *Gemeinde*. This is true also for the 19th century germany (i pointed to state-specific "commune"-related legislation from 1808 / 1818). So, communes existed already in that time and also during the german *Reich* (seems to be one part of your question), but AFAIK the only case of *Kreise* without subdivisions were cities that "acted" itself as a *Kreis* in legal aspects.

Comment: I can't rule out definitely that there was some *Kreise* compassing only one commune / *Gemeinde*, but this is extremly unlikely since the purpose of the *Kreise* was to encompass multiple communes.

Comment: Replace circle with County as understood in the US (and not as in Britain). Dorf, Gemeinde, Stadt (Villiage, Town, City) belongs in most cases to a Kreis (County). A County in Prussia belongs to a Province, The Province belongs to the Kingdom. Some cities can be independent from a County. Some Cities can also be a Province (Berlin, Bremen, Hamburg...) I have never heard of a Town (Gemeinde) being outside of a Country. At present when a Town has more that 100,000 peaple it becomes a City.

Comment: @tohuwawohu The Landkreise were established in Prussia long before 1880 in 1812 with the "Stein-Hardenbergsche Reformen". First it was a fully state dependent administrative level, later (and now) it is both "Untere Verwaltungsbehörde" (lowest administrative level of the state) and association of Gemeinden (so "kommunal" in contrast to "staatlich").